# nuget is not a recognized as an internal or external command not working for Visual studio 2015

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I am trying to create a Nuget Package. Was in the process of Nuget Manifest file.
Got this error while running the command in command prompt nuget spec.

Comment: Have you find the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run `nuget spec` in the Visual Studio 2015 NuGet Package Manager Console. It is only for finding, installing and updating existing packages; you can't use it to create new ones.

If you are trying to create a new NuGet package, then you will need to use the separate standalone NuGet CLI tool. This executable provides the commands you are looking for. For more information, see the ["Install pre-requisites" section of Microsoft Docs' NuGet quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package#install-pre-requisites).